# Error in new DD4T MVC4 Setup

Tags: 2013, dd4t

I am trying to do a PoC for DD4T MVC4 Application with SDL Tridion 2013. I am facing two problems in it.

1) When I am hitting the exact page URL, I am getting HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found. It says that the page doesn't exist at the Physical Path. I am not sure, why it is looking the page at Physical Path. I tried to Debug the code, but it is not entering into the code with this URL.

URL like : localhost:54078/abc.html

2) When I hit the URL like localhost:54078/abc, then I see that it enters in the code, but then it throws the error, No PageFactory Configured.

Please help

Thanks & Regards
Sharad Sangal

Comment: I added <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> line in Web.Config and now with the Page URL it is going inside the code. But I am still getting No PageFactory Configured Error. PLease Help

Comment: The issue is resolved now. Created DD4T MVC4 App with Nuget package and it is running now.